# How can I clip a geo projection using multiple polygons (for multiple resulting viewports) in D3?

Tags: svg, d3.js, geo

**TL;DR:** Trying to render a non-contiguous fuller projection but feature polygons span multiple "viewports". How do I avoid that (cut polygons at viewport edges)?

**Full version:** I'd like to render a non-contiguous fuller projection (tiles separated by "space" and not traditionally aligned) of geo data. How do I get this to work in D3? An example of the rough layout I'm looking for can be [found here](http://aragos.net/upload/productionlayout.svg).

I think I've figured out how to write the projection itself, based on the extremely helpful work by Jason Davis at [jasondavies.com/maps/airocean](http://jasondavies.com/maps/airocean). Since I don't want a contiguous map representation I merely hardcode the transformation from gnomonic to relative position for each face rather than doing matrix multiplications for shared tile edges. However, features that cross tile boundaries currently get rendered as a single SVG path, thus causing them to smear all across the canvas (connecting the tiles where they are present), as in this [simple layout example](http://aragos.net/upload/smearedpolygons.png).

I noticed that Jason already forked D3 for his fuller projection, adding d3.geo.projection.clipPolygon to render a non-rectangular viewport. But even that logic seems to be limited to a single viewport encompassing the entire map. Looking at clipPolygon's implementation I'm not sure if I could adapt it to handle multiple polygons in any reasonable amount of time.

Note that as I don't plan to publish this as a webpage (it's the base for a physical layout in an art project :) I'd be perfectly happy if the render time is long and I had one projection per face and the clip outline just encompassed a single face each. Unfortunately even that seems beyond me right now, if I pass a single tile's outline as clip polygon, I only get that face rendered but completely filled with a single color (feature polygon).

Any help appreciated! :)

The "polyhedron" projection I'm using:

```
d3.geo.woodcut = function(nodes, face) {
  var r = π / 1.5;

  var baseTransform = [
    Math.cos(r), Math.sin(r), 0,
    -Math.sin(r), Math.cos(r), 0
  ];

  var mesh = [], outline = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
    var node = nodes[i];   
    var ring = node.face.slice();
    ring.push(ring[0]);
    var centroid = d3.geo.centroid({type: "Polygon", coordinates: [ring]});

    // add mesh
    var edges = faceEdges(node.face);
    for (var j = 0; j < edges.length; ++j) {
      // todo: skip some sides for indented triangle
      mesh.push(edges[j].map(function(d) { return d3.geo.interpolate(d, centroid)(ε); }));
    }

    // add to outline
    if (i == 4/*true*/) {
      var tmp = node.face.slice();
      tmp.push(tmp[0]);
      for (var j = 0; j < tmp.length; ++j) {
        outline.push(tmp.map(function(d) { return d3.geo.interpolate(d, centroid)(ε); }));
      }
    }

    node.transform = baseTransform.slice();
    node.transform[2] = i * 1.5;
  }

  function forward(λ, φ) {
    var node = face(λ, φ),
        point = node.project([λ * degrees, φ * degrees]),
        t;
    if (t = node.transform) {
      return [
        t[0] * point[0] + t[1] * point[1] + t[2],
        -(t[3] * point[0] + t[4] * point[1] + t[5])
      ];
    }
    point[1] = -point[1];
    return point;
  }

  var projection = d3.geo.projection(forward)/*.clipPolygon(outline)*/;
  projection.mesh = mesh;

  return projection;
}
```

Comment: The letters π, λ, φ are used as variables look very cool!